# Moving long discussions to chat broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, chat

Tried to move the comments on this issue:

[Passing dynamic order by in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085149/passing-dynamic-order-by-in-stored-procedure/15085262#15085262)

To chat.  The comments were copied successfully:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25136/discussion-between-andomar-and-jitendra-pancholi

But the comments are still visible on the answer.

Shouldn't the comments have been moved to chat?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

Comments are copied to chat for reference and context, so those visiting the chat conversation have them available in one place. However, remember - comments are the most ephemeral things in the system - they're designed to facilitate short discussions where any useful results should be moved into the question or answer.

Comments copied to chat remain under the post so that can happen, and are (typically) flagged/marked as obsolete and removed afterwards. If we just moved them to chat, the useful bits might be overlooked and not made a part of the parent post.

Comment: What's "marking as obsolete"?  Can I mark as obsolete, and remove comments?

Comment: @Andomar Yes, you can flag a comment as obsolete.

Comment: Is it an idea to alter the wording of "move comments" to "copy comments to chat and mark them as obsolete" ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Why would they be automatically moved to chat? There might be some very good information in those comments.

Moving it to chat would basically mean hiding then (even though chat is public, it's much more obscure than comments on a post).

Answer (score 1):

Even when you move them, they actually stay under the answer. It's not a bug.

So "move" here basically means "copied", not "cut-and-paste".

Comment: 'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.'

Comment: @Andomar you could ask for a feature-request in that case. :P